# Confused regarding the use of shopping carts in general

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I have a project which will need a shopping cart which is where my confusion begins. The payment gateway we have in mind supports a lot of carts but does that mean I can't create a custom cart myself form the ground up? We're just selling around 10 products so I was hoping to create a customized cart for my client.

This is a PHP/MySQL site and since this is my first ecommerce project and I'm afraid that if I create a custom cart I won't be able to link it to the gateway. Am I just being paranoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the gateway and how things are passed across.

In general, if the payment gateway supports multiple carts, there will be a technical way for you to link into it but you'll need details of their API (How to pass over items, quantities, taxes, shipping info, etc...)

Worst-case, you can look at how the supported carts do it and duplicate the functionality.

The best place to look for information is the payment gateway themselves - sometimes they offer SDKs or APIs in various languages. Of course, this all assumes the payment gateway are willing to let you use a custom solution (most are)

I would point out the e-commerce is a high risk area of development and you should make absolutely certain you know what you're doing before using it in a production environment. You need to be as certain as you can be that there are no bugs/flaws in your code that could result in over/under charging, SQL injection attacks, etc.

Comment: +1 for last paragraph. One will almost certainly fail at reinventing the wheel well.

Comment: @WaleedKhan I was forced to implement one from the ground up once and almost lost the will to live with all the validation, auditing, checksums, callbacks, etc required to do it robustly and well.

Comment: Thanks @basic. I'm looking at some carts now. Is opencart any good?

Comment: You're welcome. I haven't used opencart so can't comment with any authority. Wikipedia has a [comparison chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_shopping_cart_software) which may be of use to you. I think you really need to decide what you're looking for in a cart - small and simple or large and complex. Do you need to worry about stock control/discounts/logging/affiliates/ordering couriers/integration with accounting software/etc ? Once you know more clearly what you want, you'll be able to more clearly decide which to pick

Comment: @Basic: I'm open to choosing a highly flexible cart as long as it's free. Can I ask what you'd use?

Comment: I've used [ZenCart](http://www.zen-cart.com/) before and had a lot of success with it but most of the time I've had to do custom carts (despite the dire warnings and being a pain in the backside). I tend to work for large clients who are already [PCI Compliant](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/documents.php?document=pci_dss_v2-0#pci_dss_v2-0) and have existing payment systems which require custom integration.

Comment: I think I'll go with OpenCart. The sample live sites are pretty impressive and the features might just be what I need. Gonna give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

If any of those supported carts are open source, then yes, you're being a bit paranoid.  You could rather easily look at the payment modules for any of them to see how the gateway wants stuff passed.  Add to that, the gateway will generally document how it expects stuff, which is how those open source modules typically get written in the first place.

With that said, though...if this is your first e-commerce site, you might want to start with an existing cart and save yourself a bunch of trouble.  There's a lot of stuff to worry about and rules to follow when you're handling credit card info and money in general, and you don't want unproven code sitting out there waiting to be exploited.  The big established carts have been out there for a while now and are less likely to be doing something totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Payment providers usually handle the security aspects of handling money.  Just make sure you are using SSL for all transactions.

That being said, there are many cart implementations out there.  I usually favor these since even if you start small, you may grow.  An existing implementation will give you this scalability rather than roll-your-own.  Unless you plan on creating differentiation for your customers by a custom implementation, use one off the shelf.